# Taking 3D vectors and generating an angular distribution plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, angle

I have a bunch of vectors that represent objects in 3D space that are flexible relative to a plane represented across the 0 axis. I can happily plot these vectors as shown below:

[image: Vectors plotted in quiver3d plot with matplotlib]

These are all plotted as unit vectors.

I want to take these vectors and plot an angular distribution of them in a 2D circle where a point is plotted for the angle from the vertical (in this case I know this to be (0,0,1)) and the angle around the 360degree.

knowing the angle from the vertical is easy enough and I already have a function to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def CalculateAngleBetweenVector(vector, vector2):
    """
    This function was mainly created to double check the angle between the input and outputs of the applyrotationmatrix function
    """
    dp = np.dot(vector, vector2)

    maga = math.sqrt((vector[0] ** 2) + vector[1] ** 2 + vector[2] ** 2)
    magb = math.sqrt((vector2[0] ** 2) + vector2[1] ** 2 + vector2[2] ** 2)
    magc = maga * magb

    dpmag = dp / magc

    angleindeg = ((math.acos(dpmag)) * 180) / math.pi

    return angleindeg
```

The issue now is that I am not sure how to calculate the angle around the circle. What would be the best way to do this?

I had the idea of potentially projecting all the vectors into 2D and then calculating the angle from the 0,1,0 or 1,0,0 axis but then I only get 0 - 180 rather than -180 to +180. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Look up the atan2 function. The angle (in radians) around the Z axis is given by atan2(x, y)

Comment: @Tharwen Thank you so much, that looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: Uh... it might actually be atan2(y, x). I can't quite remember. Try them both.

Comment: @Tharwen yeah I think it is atan2(y,x) looking at wikipedia and the python math module just so happens to have this exact equation in it already :D